# Java to convert PDF to TIFF using Ghostscript

Tags: java, pdf, tiff, ghostscript

I am using Ghostscript API to convert PDF to single page TIFF images.

However i am getting an error:

```
java.io.IOException \
   Temporary file \
   C:\DOCUME~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\ghost4j\net.sf.ghost4j.document.PDFDocument \
   cannot be deleted
```

This temporary file is created when Simplerenderer object renders the document and saves in List≶image>.

Can this temporary file be deleted during process run? Do i have to use some wait method for the process to complete? Is there any lock involved?

Answer (score 2):

I thought it is a well-known fact amongst [java](/questions/tagged/java) programmers that as long as some stream on the file is open, it is locked (at least for the Windows implementation of the JVM). So it cannot be deleted.

Did you close the stream properly before trying to delete the file?

See also

- [delete temporary file in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026479/delete-temporary-file-in-java)
- [I can't delete a file in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991489/i-cant-delete-a-file-in-java)
- [Java keeps lock on files for no apparent reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586830/java-keeps-lock-on-files-for-no-apparent-reason)

Comment: while this doesn't exactly answer the question, it gives good links regarding issues closing / deleting files with java

Comment: That's great if you're writing the file handler yourself. Not so great if you're dealing with a library that does it for you.